# pythonic way to write the code for search and replace string

Tags: python, regex, replace

I have written code to search and replace string in make command as per user input

`make language='english' id=234 version=V1 path='/bin'`

In above code i searched `version=V1` and replace version with `version=V2`

```
import re
strings = "make language='english' id=234 version=V1 path='/bin'"
search_pattern= re.search('version=(.*?)\s', strings)
old_str = search_pattern.group(1)
print test.replace(old_str, "V2")
```

Can anyone help me write above code in pythonic way or any other way to write above code

Comment: Why not `strings.replace("V1", "V2")`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very easy if you use [`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace)

```
String = "make language='english' id=234 version=V1 path='/bin'"
String = String.replace("version=V1", "version=V2")
```